# What's the difference between writing 'Effect.Highlight(...)' and 'new Effect.Highlight(...)'?

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous

Both `Effect.Highlight(...)` and `new Effect.Highlight(...)` work just fine.
So whats the difference in both usages, if any.

I started wondering about this because resharper (6) is showing me a warning when I use `new Effect.Highlight(...)`: Expression statement is not assignment or call.

Manu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `Highlight()` function is static, so you can call it either way, but the simplest one will always work:

```
Effect.Highlight(...)
```

Whereas instantiating a `new` object might not (if the class isn't supposed to be instantiated)

However, Javascript is generally soft on those kinds of function calls, so I'm guessing you could also use:

```
(new Effect).Highlight(...)
```

as long as you enclose the instantiation in parenthesis so the interpreter will know what you're trying to do

Comment: Does doing a `new Effect.Highlight(..)` without assigning its result to a variable automatically _store_ it in the global window object?

Comment: Nope - it will only exist while the Highlight() call runs